# node.js: how to use fibrous to return data from the request library

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, coffeescript

I am trying to use the [fibrous](https://github.com/goodeggs/fibrous) library with [request](https://github.com/request/request) to return the body of an HTTP request synchronously, but I am having trouble with the flow.

I wrote a very simple helper function:

```
getPage = (url, callback)->
    request(url, (error, response, body) ->
        if error
            callback(error, null)
        if not error and response.statusCode is 200
            console.log ("got here")
            callback(null, body)
    )
```

If I want to turn this into a synchronous call, do I just do something like:

```
syncRequest = fibrous((url)->
    console.log(sync.getPage("http://www.google.com"))
)
```

If not, what is the correct way to structure my code so that I get a synchronous call to request?

Answer (score 0):

ok I got this working with the following code:

```
syncGETRequest = fibrous((url, options)->
    data = request.sync.get(url, options)
    console.log(data)
)

runTest = ()->
    syncGETRequest.sync("http://www.google.com", {})

fibrous.run(runTest)
```